# Serialización JLabel

Tags: java

Soy uno de las millones de personas que son autodidácticas o al menos intentan serlo, esta vez tengo un problema (a parte de mi desorden) intento "guardar" un jlabel, que sufre cambios (tipo de letra y color) en el programa.

Intento guardar esos cambios y aplicárselos a otra jlabel que tengo ahí..pero no puedo lograrlo, acá dejo el código, espero puedan ayudarme, pero sobre todo entender el código ... Gracias

// al parecer si serializa pero no puedo recuperar la información y/o usarla

```
public class Pruebas {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Marco mm=new Marco();
    mm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mm.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                // Ask for confirmation before terminating the program.
                int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mm, 
                        "...",
                        "...", 
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                if (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        mm.Guardar(mm.x);
                        System.exit(0);
                }
        }

    });
    mm.setVisible(true);

}

}
class Marco extends JFrame{
JPanel a;
JLabel x,z,y;
JButton b,c,j;
GridLayout gr;
public Marco(){
    setBounds(400,200,250,100);
    setLayout(null);
    x=new JLabel("Hola");
    z=new JLabel("Adios");
    y=new JLabel("");
    b=new JButton("Cambiar");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            x.setFont(new Font("Lucida Console",Font.BOLD,13));
            x.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

        }
    });
    c=new JButton("Cargar");
    c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Recuperar(y);

        }
    });
    j=new JButton("Ap. Cam.");
    j.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            z.setFont(y.getFont());
            z.setForeground(y.getForeground());

        }
    });
    gr=new GridLayout(0,2);
    a=new JPanel();
    a.setBounds(20,5,200,50);
    a.setLayout(gr);
    a.add(x);
    a.add(b);
    a.add(z);
    a.add(c);
    a.add(j);
    add(a);

}
public void Guardar(JLabel y){
    try{
        ObjectOutputStream Salida=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Julio   Cesar/Desktop/etiqueta.xx"));
        Salida.writeObject(y);
        Salida.close();
        System.out.println("ok");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("....");
    }

}
public void Recuperar(JLabel d){
    try{
        ObjectInputStream Entrada=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Julio         Cesar/Desktop/etiqueta.xx"));
        d=(JLabel) Entrada.readObject();
        Entrada.close();
        System.out.println("rp");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("....");
    }

}
}
```